# I cannot change my Minecraft name as it say something went wrong and to try again later

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to change my username I am told something has gone wrong and I have to try again later. I wait half an hour and it does not work. Then an hour, a day and so on. This problem keeps occurring and I have no idea how to stop this problem. The exact words I have received are:

> 'Oops! Something went wrong and we could not change your profile name. Are you sure you entered the correct password? If the problem persists, try again later.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a possibility you are entering the wrong password as the error suggests? Perhaps you should try resetting your Microsoft account password and trying to change your username after doing so.

Comment: Thank you I will try this.

Comment: It has worked Thank you very much

Comment: If this worked, you should mark it as the best answer. It helps others as it signifies it was the best answer and it helps me by giving me a reputation boost.  Glad I could help!